# Moving from MySQL 5.x to 8.x - fails due to column called "over"

Tags: mysql, migration, window-functions

Interesting and frustrating one, this.  We have an old database that is still very actively used via multiple Excel files with VBA in, including archived projects with such files in.

There's a bit of code that does this:

SELECT value FROM myTable WHERE someIndex = 1 AND over < 3.2

This works perfectly on 5.x as our table has a column called "over" with suitable values in.

However, it fails on 8.x because there's a new keyword that's been added for windowing, called "OVER".  So obviously it's now invalid syntax, where it wasn't before.

Is there any way I can disable windowing keywords for a specific database?  I realise I can change the VBA script to put "over" in quotes, but as most of our archived projects have the Excel files read-only, that's not an option.

Any suggestions which don't involve changing the Excel VBA would be very much appreciated!  Otherwise we're stuck with 5.x and can't move to 8.x.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: I think unfortunately there's no way to *disable* such a feature specifically, in the newer versions of MySQL (but I'm not a MySQL expert so I'll await for someone else to answer). This would be a core feature of the language engine. And honestly it would be the wrong way to go IMO, because window functions are very important and helpful tools, which you shouldn't look to limit your querying abilities from. Rather you should do the *right* thing and update your queries to be syntactically valid, despite it being additional work for your upgrade path.

Comment: Either rename column and edit all queries or revert MySQL version. PS. Window functions were introduced in ANSI/ISO SQL 2003. I.e. the word `'OVER'` is a keyword already 18 years...

Comment: Thank you everyone and I completely agree with all your comments.  Although OVER was introduced in SQL 2003, it didn't make it to MySQL until MySQL8.0 so that's not really relevant (i.e. the code was fine when it was written).  As changing old, archived scripts isn't an option, I think we'll have to have a 5.x server for those projects but use 8.x for active and new projects.  Many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`over` is now a keyword -- as of MySQL 8.0.  (And there are several other 'new' keywords that will cause syntax errors.)  8.1 (some year) will probably introduce more new keywords.

To avoid such in the future, put backtics (`) around each column name and table name.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to disable certain keywords or built-in functions in MySQL.

You'd have to change the source code of MySQL itself and build a customized version. There is no guidance on how to do this, since it is not a typically supported usage of MySQL. You'd have to learn a lot about the internals of MySQL code to do it. And you'd end up with an ongoing maintenance task for yourself, if you wanted to upgrade MySQL ever again, you'd have to apply the same patch to each future version.

I think you'll find that it would be less work delimit identifiers in SQL queries in your VBA code, even if you have to rewrite them from scratch.